# How do I access originally passed array after sorting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

When passing an array [2,1,3,5,3,2,1] to this function, I choose to sort from least to greatest. However, when I try to log or work with the original array, both "sorted" and "a" log the same sorted array. I am unsure as to why the sorting is going beyond the scope of just the variable "sorted".

```
function firstDuplicate(a) {
    let sorted = a.sort((a,b) => a - b);
    let duplicates = [];
    let indexes = [];

    console.log(sorted);
    console.log(a);
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: make a copy ... `sorted = a.slice().sort......`

Comment: ...embarrassing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` sorts the array *in place* - it does not copy the array and create a new one, the original array is modified. If you want to separate the original and the sorted, you should explicitly make a copy first before sorting, which you can do by calling `slice(0)` on the original:

```js
function firstDuplicate(a) {
  let sorted = a.slice(0).sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let duplicates = [];
  let indexes = [];

  console.log(sorted);
  console.log(a);
}
firstDuplicate([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1])
```

Comment: I didn't downvote (not sure why it was, other than possibly a blatant duplicate), but the `0` is optional, just saying.

Answer (score 1):

`sort` destructively sorts the array and returns it. There is no more "unsorted" array. If you want the unsorted array later, clone it before sorting:

```
let unsorted = Array.from(a)
a.sort(...)
```

(EDIT: It doesn't really matter whether you sort the clone, like Jaromanda X in his comment, or the original like me, as long as you start out with two arrays.)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript arrays are Sorted in place, that is why changes are reflected in both the arrays. What you can do is clone your original array and then sort that cloned array. You can clone a array using ‘Array.slice()’,(Array.slice() returns a new array).

```
   let sorted = a.slice().sort();
```

Answer (score -1):

you need create a copy from original array, try this

```
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
        let array = this;
        let newArray = [];
        // clone the objects in array
        let cloneObject = function(item){
            let newObject = {};
            for(o in item){
                if(typeof(item[o])!="object"){
                    newObject[o] = item[o];   
                }
                else{
                    newObject[o] = cloneObject(item[o]);   
                }
            }                
         return newObject;

        }
        for(let i =0; i<array.length;i++){
            let item = array[i];
            // if item is not object add value to array
            if(typeof(item)!="object"){
                newArray.push(item);
            }
            // if element is object, clone item and add to array
            else{
                newArray.push(cloneObject(item));
            }
        }
        return newArray;

    }

        function firstDuplicate(a) {
                let sorted = a.clone().sort((a, b) => a - b);
                let duplicates = [];
                let indexes = [];

                console.log(sorted);
                console.log(a);
        }
        var element = [2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1];
        firstDuplicate(element)
```

Comment: There's no need to do a deep clone just to access the original sort order with any type of elements in the array and certainly no need to even clone with an array of numbers like the OP showed in their question.